# IBM DataPower write error(8)

Tags: ssl, ibm-datapower

Our DP can act as both client and server in our architecture . First, our members call our service, then our asynchronous service call theirs. First transaction completed successfully but in second transaction, I am getting error below:

```
wsgw (OI_MemberServices): DP Error: 0x0113001c|0x00000000|Connection error
wsgw (OI_MemberServices): Connection error
wsgw (OI_MemberServices): Error in stream. Descriptor number unavailable. Additional information: Write error (8)       
wsgw (OI_MemberServices): Network Error on back side server https://BE_MEMBER_YKR:8443/tr.com.gnx.matchIdentitiesResult.web/matchIdentitiesResultWs
```

But, I have noticed something today. At top of these logs:

```
valcred (OIClientValCred): SSLProxyProfile 'OI2WSSLPP': connection error: certificate not trusted
```

Actually, I did not pay attention to it first because it had different tid. Could it possible that they are related somehow? There is also something else, we use same SSL cert in our test env for same member and nothing went wrong so far.

**What I did to solve this:**

- I had tcpdump for both side. Nothing suspicious.
- Their service is up and reachable.
- SSL Proxy Profile > OI2WSSLPP > Permit Connections to Insecure SSL Servers : off > on
- SSL Proxy Profile > OIClientSSLPP > Permit Connections to Insecure SSL Servers : off > on
- Crypto Profile > OIClientCP > Permit insecure SSL renegotiation to a legacy SSL client : disabled > enabled

All advises are much appriciated!!
tnx

DP Firmware: XI52.6.0.0.3

Comment: In my practice "write error(8)" usually tells about trusted certificates problems duing 2-way SSL communications. So check what the certs you have in "Crypto validation credentials" and what the certs client or server actually sends to your DP.

Comment: Hi. I think you didn't solve it, you disable it. So clearly is a cert problem. You have to match valid certificates.